# Issue with Eigen's triangularView

Tags: c++, eigen

I am using Eigen C++ library's triangularView feature to skip computation of upper triangular part of a matrix like this:

```
C.triangularView<Lower>() = A*B;
```

This works as I intend, but when I use "StrictlyLower" to skip computation of the diagonal too, the resulting matrix seems corrupted. Here is example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   MatrixXi A, B, C, D;
   A = MatrixXi::Ones(5,5);
   B = MatrixXi::Ones(5,5);

   C = MatrixXi::Zero(5,5);
   D = MatrixXi::Zero(5,5);

   C.triangularView<Lower>() = A*B;
   D.triangularView<StrictlyLower>() = A*B;

   cout << "\n C = \n " << C << endl;
   cout << "\n D = \n " << D << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
C = 
5 0 0 0 0
5 5 0 0 0
5 5 5 0 0
5 5 5 5 0
5 5 5 5 5

D = 
5 5 5 5 0
0 5 5 5 0
0 0 5 5 0
0 0 0 5 0
0 0 0 0 5
```

Now `C` looks as I expect. But `D` should be the same except 0's on diagonal.
Why does `D` look like this?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in Eigen. You can try to download the latest version. If that doesn't work, the best thing you can do is fill in a [bug report](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Bugzilla).

Comment: Yes, this looks like a bug and I will report it. There are no examples of how to use triangularView in Eigen documentation so I wasn't sure if I was using the concept correctly.